# Como, usando java, deixar em negrito determinadas partes de uma TextView?

Tags: android, textview

Gostaria de saber como fazer para que uma determinada parte de um texto que será exibido em uma **TEXTVIEW** ficasse em negrito:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria que o texto exibido ficasse assim: Valor total => **R$ 1100.**

Activity:

```js
package genesysgeneration.stackall;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView tvValor;
    private Button btnMais100;
    int valor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tvValor=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvValor);
        btnMais100=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnMais100);
        valor=0;

        btnMais100.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                valor+=100;
                tvValor.setText(String.valueOf("Valor total => R$ " + valor + "."));

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Sei que poderia criar uma outra TextView, mas não me serve. Sei também que poderia fazer isso no .xml da TextView, mas é inviável, pois o texto é dinâmico (não tanto no exemplo, mas no meu real projeto onde quero usar isso).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a classe [SpannableString](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html), ela permite anexar objectos de *markup* a partes especificas de um texto.

```
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
String label = "Valor total => ";
String valor = "R$ 1100";

SpannableString textoNegrito = new SpannableString(label + valor);
textoNegrito.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), label.length(), textoNegrito.length(), 0);
textView.setText(textoNegrito);
```

Comment: no caso de um texto, tal coisa fica inviável

Comment: Não entendi. Pode explicar?